# Need a .NET WinForms IP Address Control

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, controls, ip-address

I need a robust, user-friendly, professional-looking .NET WinForms IP address control for use in a project I'm working on.  This control, at a minimum, should support IPv4 addressing and ideally would support IPv6 addressing as well.  I would prefer a free control with C# source code, but don't mind paying for one.

I am using .NET 3.5 SP1, so anything .NET 2.0 and greater should be sufficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tada.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/IpAddrCtrlLib.aspx

The latest version of this control is found here (thanks Pat):

http://code.google.com/p/ipaddresscontrollib/

Comment: Daniel, have you used this one personally?  Looks promising...

Comment: Project was moved to Github in the meantime: https://github.com/m66n/ipaddresscontrollib

Answer (score 3):

I found following ip address control.  Its really good.
http://sanity-free.org/127/an_ipaddress_control_the_win32_sysipaddress32_control_in_csharp.html

Answer (score 2):

Get the latest code at http://code.google.com/p/ipaddresscontrollib/